# Sorting summary data in Yii2 grid view

Tags: gridview, widget, yii2

I have 3 tables, User, Play, and UserPlay which is a junction table for the other ones. Im working on a gridview widget of Play table and i want it to display the total number of users signed up for each play. I managed to achieve this by setting up a userlist getter in the Play table model, like this:

```
public function getUserList()
{
     return $this->hasMany(UserPlay::className(), ['play_id' => 'id'])->count();
}
```

Now, i'd like to enable sorting and possibly filtering this data in the gridview, but so far i was unsuccesful in this struggle. My best attempt was that i managed to enable the sorting, but after clicking the column i got a database error saying userList column doesnt exist. Any help would be greatly appriciated !

Comment: what kind of sorting do u want to do? the count in ascending & descending order?

Comment: Yes, from most users to least and from least to most.

Comment: Hello, struggled the same. Here is the solution: [Yii 2.0: Filter & Sort by Summary Data in GridView Yii 2.0](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/679/filter-sort-by-summary-data-in-gridview-yii-2-0/)